# "Email has already been taken" error on db:seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am running through Hartl's Rails tutorial, but when I try to seed Microposts I am getting the error: "ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken"

I did db:migrate:reset followed by db:seed which throws up the error. Is there something wrong with what I am trying to seed?

```
User.create!(name: "Example User",
             email: "example@railstutorial.org",
             password: "foobar",
             password_confirmation: "foobar",
             admin: true,
             activated: true,
             activated_at: Time.zone.now)

99.times do |n|
  name= Faker::Name.name
  email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
  password = "password"
  User.create!(name: name,
               email: email,
               password: password,
               password_confirmation: password,
               activated: true,
               activated_at: Time.zone.now)
end

  users = User.order(:created_at).take(6)
  50.times do
    content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(word_count: 5)
    users.each { |user| user.microposts.create!(content: content) }
  end
```

Comment: Since you're using Faker, consider [Faker::Internet.unique.email](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/faker/Faker/Internet#uuid-class_method). I don't see anything wrong, there must be an existing User. Check the database is empty before you seed; run the console and check `User.all`.

Comment: Can you show us your User class, please?

Comment: If I do User.all I come up with two users, my Example User and then one more, so it is not seeding the users along with the microposts.

Comment: Are you clearing your users table between runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly happened but I went ahead and reset my migrations once more and when I reseeded it worked. So if anyone else has this problem in the future, just clear the database again and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably already created some records in the database, which invokes validation. To check this, run the console `rails c` and then type `User.first`.

If you have some records run `rake db:reset` to reset database.

If you want to be able to run the seed multiple times, write

```rb
User.find_or_create_by(email: email) do |u|
  u.name: name,
  u.password: password,
  u.password_confirmation: password,
  u.activated: true,
  u.activated_at: Time.zone.now
end
```

instead your code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `create!` user `create` so if the email address is already taken, the record would not be created and the script gracefully continues, and you won't get an exception.

Comment: I would recommend sticking with `create!` since sometimes it would be more useful to see the error than having some of the seed items skipped

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a syntax error when calling Rake :: .....
It worked for me to update the gem with gem 'faker', '~> 2.15', '> = 2.15.1'
Then rails db: migrate: reset and rails db: seed.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make use of text formatting.